# Delphi 10 dcc32 command line error "file not found: myApp.res"

Tags: delphi

I build my app and i copied the commandline from the output window to one batch file.
it looks like :

```
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\cgrc.exe" -c65001 myApp.vrc -fomyApp.res
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\dcc32.exe" -$J+ -$D0 -$L- -$C- -$Y-................
```

It executes well except the mentioned error.
I noticed that the myApp.res that the IDE creates, the commandline execution deletes it.
What's wrong ?

PS. the same error occurs even i erase the first line (...\cgrc.exe ...)

Comment: Probably doing this wrong. Use msbuild.

Comment: I haven't installed RAD Studio Command Prompt to run MSbuild.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: You should use msbuild

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ 2nd last item on that page includes msbuild

Comment: @Dave No, you don't need to download anything extra, the Delphi installer puts in place what is needed.